# Log in to Jenkins through URL rewriting

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to log in to Jenkins directly through the URL instead of logging in through the webpage.

For eg: `localhost:8080/username = username&password = password`

Comment: You know that logging in via GET parameters is extremely insecure? It will end up in the browsing history and in log files on the web server as well..

Comment: Security isn't really a concern

Comment: Never.. :-) ...